# Is reciting Takbeer three times after every farj salat in Ayyam-E-Tashrik days a Mustahab work?

Tags: bidah, takbir, mustahab

During Eid-Ul-Azha, we usually recite Takbeer (Allahu akbar Allahu akbar, La ilaha illallahu Allahu akbar wallahu akbar wa lillahil hamd) after every Farj salat in Ayyam-E-Tashrik one time.

But recently, our Imam started to recite it three times and told that, one time is wajib and three times is Mustahab. Yesterday I went to a relative's house and went to the masjid there and found they also started reciting three times.

I want to know the actual thing, Is it really a Sunnat/Mustahab? Or is it just a local fitna/bidyat?

Comment: reciting 1 time is Wajib and more than 1 time is Sunnah not a Biddah

Comment: any reference? thanks @servant

Comment: Related https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27739/what-do-sunni-muslims-recite-during-zil-hijjah-month-after-prayers/27740#27740

Answer (score 2):

There is no hadith attributed to the Prophet ﷺ about *takbīrat* during the time of Eid al-Adha apart from:

> حدثنا عفان، حدثنا أبو عوانة، حدثنا يزيد بن أبي زياد، عن مجاهد، عن ابن عمر، عن النبي ﷺ قال: ما من أيام أعظم عند الله، ولا أحب إليه من العمل فيهن، من هذه الأيام العشر، فأكثروا فيهن من التهليل والتكبير والتحميد
>
> <sub>*— NOTE: My own translation, so treat with care:*</sub>
>
> Narrated by Ibn 'Umar that the Prophet ﷺ said: There are no days in which righteous deeds are more beloved to Allah than those ten days, so increase [your] utterances of profession of faith [*tahlīl*, or saying *La ilāha illa Allah*), utterances of His Greatness (*takbīr*, or saying *Allahu Akbar*), and utterances of praise of Him (*tahmīd*, or saying *Al-hamdu li Allah*).
>
> <sub>— [Musnad Ahmad, Hadith 5294](https://shamela.ws/book/25794/4696)</sub>

Apart from that, there are different opinions of how many takbīrat one can (one or three), the words to use, and the time of doing them (see in Arabic only [Sharh al-Zurqānī 'Ala Muatta' Malik](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=1873&bk_no=77&flag=1), Arabic: شرح الزرقاني على موطأ الإمام مالك) based on what some of the companions practiced. So doing  *takbīrat* is not bid'ah, but there is nothing attributed to the Prophet ﷺ that restricts *takbīrat* to only after prayers, or to limit them in number.

Comment: { كَانَ النَّبِيُّ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ يُكَبِّرُ فِي صَلَاةِ 
الْفَجْرِ يَوْمَ عَرَفَةَ إلَى صَلَاةِ الْعَصْرِ مِنْ آخِرِ أَيَّامِ التَّشْرِيقِ حِينَ يُسَلِّمُ مِنْ الْمَكْتُوبَاتِ } رَوَاهُ الدَّارَقُطْنِيّ .
رَوَى جَابِرٌ ، { أَنَّ النَّبِيَّ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ صَلَّى الصُّبْحَ يَوْمَ عَرَفَةَ ، وَأَقْبَلَ عَلَيْنَا ، فَقَالَ : اللَّهُ أَكْبَرُ اللَّهُ   أَكْبَرُ .
وَمَدَّ التَّكْبِيرَ إلَى الْعَصْرِ مِنْ آخِرِ أَيَّامِ التَّشْرِيقِ } 
http://www.feqhweb.com/vb/t14936.html